# raspberry pi rebooting all the time

Tags: raspbmc, power-supply, xbian

My Raspberry Pi keeps on rebooting all the time.
It boots up just fine, I can use it for some time (3 to 15min), then it reboots.

Some of the things I've tried:
-Changing the transformer, had a 5V 1.2 Amp, so I bought a new 5V 2.0 Amp with a new USB Cable
-Had XBian as the OS, now I have RaspBMC
-SD Card, had a 8Gb PNY, and bought a new Samsung SD Card
-I used a Wifi usb Adapter, but changed to Ethernet cable (so, no usb devices where connected at all)
-Even tried getting it out of it's case, and tried a different wall socket/plug (for the transformer)

And this still happens, so is there anything else I can try? Or did the raspberry get damaged somehow?

Comment: There are many possibilities. Speculating would be pointless. The MOST COMMON is power issues. You really need to MEASURE the supply voltage. What is the PSU; mobile chargers are often unsuitable. See http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: My problem is that I don't have a multimeter.
And buying a cheap one just for this doesn't seem like a good idea.
But I'll dig a bit more into the power supply "stuff"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced a lot of crashes and reboots with XBMC (with XBian and RaspBMC) though it got much more stable in the last year. But especially some XBMC plugins are really unstable.

I would try running the RPi with a standard Raspbian installation. Try to boot into LXDE desktop and maybe play some videos with the omxplayer.

If it does not crash, try a fresh RaspBMC installation. If this does not crash, try to add your desired plugins. Reboot after installing every plugin and wait if the RPi crashes.

If it is still rebooting with a standard Raspbian installation on a SD card from [this list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards), no USB devices attached and a real 2.0 A power supply connected, I would think, the Raspberry Pi is broken somehow. Try to [troubleshoot power problems](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems) like Milliways mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Nice tips, I'll try your troubleshooting.
See if I can find the source of the problems.
Thanks.